# Android getview move ROW to top with if conditions

Tags: java, android

Android getview with list view i need move row to top position with conditions. Now list view shows users and groups. I need move groups in top positions in list view

```
if (Dialog.Type.GROUP.equals(dialog.getType()))
```

I need group list moved to top. This my full code. Or if there is any way if string contain specific value can row move top?

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    Dialog dialog = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_dialog, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.avatarImageView = (RoundedImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.avatar_imageview);
        viewHolder.nameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_textview);
        viewHolder.lastMessageTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.last_message_textview);
        viewHolder.unreadMessagesTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(
                R.id.unread_messages_textview);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    List<DialogOccupant> dialogOccupantsList = dataManager.getDialogOccupantDataManager().getDialogOccupantsListByDialogId(
            dialog.getDialogId());

    if (Dialog.Type.PRIVATE.equals(dialog.getType())) {
        User opponentUser = ChatUtils.getOpponentFromPrivateDialog(
                UserFriendUtils.createLocalUser(currentUser), dialogOccupantsList);
        if (opponentUser.getFullName() != null) {
            viewHolder.nameTextView.setText(opponentUser.getFullName());
            displayAvatarImage(opponentUser.getAvatar(), viewHolder.avatarImageView);
        } else {
            viewHolder.nameTextView.setText(resources.getString(R.string.deleted_user));
            dataManager.getDialogDataManager().deleteById(dialog.getDialogId());
        }
    } else {
        viewHolder.nameTextView.setText(dialog.getTitle());
        viewHolder.avatarImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder_group);
        displayGroupPhotoImage(dialog.getPhoto(), viewHolder.avatarImageView);
    }


    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {

    public RoundedImageView avatarImageView;
    public TextView nameTextView;
    public TextView lastMessageTextView;
    public TextView unreadMessagesTextView;
}
```